# Read specific column from a csv with DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem getting the 2nd column values from a csv file.

The following code writes data to the csv file

```
def save_tweet_to_csv(ticker, tweet, emotion, confidence):
    file = Path(url_path + ticker + '_tweets.csv')
    if file.is_file():
        mode = 'a'
    else: 
        mode = 'w'
    with open(url_path + ticker + '_tweets.csv', mode, newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['tweet', 'emotion', 'confidence']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if mode == 'w':
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'tweet': tweet, 'emotion': emotion, 'confidence': confidence})
```

and I am trying to get the *emotion* column from the csv the following way

```
def plot_tweets_csv(ticker):
    file = Path(url_path + ticker + '_tweets.csv')
    emotions = []
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader :
            print(row['emotion'])
```

But I keep getting that

> File ....\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 87, in **init**
>       self.reader = reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds) TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: You're passing a `Path` object to csv.DictReader, you should pass an open (for reading) `file` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need to change from `file` to `csvfile`

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    ...
```